# How to access a subfield present in an Interface?

Tags: go

I want to fetch url value i.e. hahaha from this interface (without using indexing) using Golang.
I want url from this interface using GOLANG

```
{
   "data" : [
       {
         "key" : "xyz",
         "val" : "ftghj"
       },
       {
          "key" : "url",
          "val" : "hahaha"
       }
    ]
}
```

I tried this method, but here i have to use indexing

- `resbodyMap := make(map[string]interface{})`
- `json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &resbodyMap)` // (here my data was in the byte format)`
- `data := resbodyMap["extendedData"]`
- `Url := extData.([]interface{})[1]`
- `mp := Url.(map[string]interface{})`
- `url := mp["val"]`

I want url from this interface using GOLANG

Comment: If you don't want to use indexing then you can't use maps. Instead, define a struct type matching the JSON structure and unmarshal into a value of that type.

Answer (score 0):

are you want like this?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var data = `{
    "data" : [
        {
          "key" : "xyz",
          "val" : "ftghj"
        },
        {
           "key" : "url",
           "val" : "hahaha"
        }
     ]
 }`

type KeyValue struct {
    Val *string `json:"val"`
}
type Data struct {
    Data []*KeyValue `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    var val string
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &Data{[]*KeyValue{nil, {&val}}})
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

However, it is not useful in actual use.